# How do I use a repeat function to reset everything and run everything over again?

Tags: javascript

I have a repeat function which runs on a button on-click event, however it's not working properly. Maybe because there are too many setIntervals running although I tried to clear them all. I also made sure to reset the variables used back to their initial values, however the moving circle keeps showing up faded when the shoot again button is pressed, so I'm assuming there's an issue with the setInterval, however, I don't know what it is.It's also not drawing the basketball again.

```js
var level = prompt("Type 1 for hard, 2 for medium, and 3 for easy.")
var dt = level / 100;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var intervalId2;
var intervalId1;

//Initializing Variables

var dt = level / 100;
const PI = 3.14;
var r = 20;
var x = r + 1;
var y = 500 / 1.2;
var a = 1;
var shift = 380;
var leftshift = 35;
var xc = 145;
var yc = 300;
var rc = 50;
var dxc = 95;
var dyc = 300;
var theta = 0;

var resetVars = function() {

  dt = 0.01;
  var x = r + 1;
  var y = 500 / 1.2;
  var xc = 145;
  var yc = 300;
  var dxc = 95;
  var dyc = 300;
  var theta = 0;
};

//resetVars();

var reset = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
  drawHoop()
};
   
  

//Interval Id to eventually clear it to stop this to shoot

var intervalID = setInterval(moveCirc, 10000 * dt);

var count = 0;
//shoot when spacebar is pressed
document.body.onkeyup = function(shoot1) {
  if (dxc <= 110 && shoot1.keyCode == 32) {
    console.log(dxc);
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    make();
    count = count + 1;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "You've made " + count + "  baskets.";
  }

  if (dxc > 110 && shoot1.keyCode == 32) {
    console.log(dxc);
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    miss();
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "You've made " + count + "  baskets.";
  }
};

var repeat = function() {
  reset();
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  clearInterval(intervalId2);
  clearInterval(intervalId1);
  resetVars();
  drawBasketball();
  drawHoop();
  moveCirc();
  intervalID = setInterval(moveCirc, 10000 * dt);


  document.body.onkeyup = function(shoot1) {
    if (dxc <= 110 && shoot1.keyCode == 32) {
      console.log(dxc);
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      make();
      count = count + 1;
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "You've made " + count + "  baskets.";
    }

    if (dxc > 110 && shoot1.keyCode == 32) {
      console.log(dxc);
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      miss();
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "You've made " + count + "  baskets.";
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500"> </canvas>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">

  
  <p id="count"></p>
  <button id="again" onclick="repeat()"> Shoot Again </button>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi, could you strip your code to only the relevent part, for your question. This is a lot of code and it's getting difficult to help you because of that. In doubt, refer to the [how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, I'm so sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This should make a stop button for a repeating function

```html
<script>
var int=self.setInterval(function, 60000);
</script>
<!-- Stop Button -->
<a href="#" onclick="window.clearInterval(int);return false;">Stop</a>
```